# Which is correct Maybe or May be

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, american-english

Is **May be** correct English? or does one need to join the words like **Maybe**?

In one of the online grammar checkers, I entered this sentence: **May be tell him about this problem**

It showed a red mark on **May be** and auto-corrected it to **Maybe.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Maybe* meaning *perhaps* is written as one word.

They are written as separate words in a sentence like *I may be late tomorrow if my car won't start.*

Comment: So Maybe and `may be` are two different things? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct.